# generate signmessage in python web3

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, nft

I am learning solidity NFT, I am trying to generate v, r ,s using python web3

```
require(owner() == ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, tokenId)), v, r, s), "owner should sign tokenId");
```

My python script

```
from web3.auto import w3
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct

msg = "contractaddrsstokenid"
private_key = "mywalletprivatekey"
message = encode_defunct(text=msg)
signed_message =  w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
print(signed_message)
```

it returns v, s, r and signature. But values are supported in contract, it says invalid format. i have changed to base64 and use. It fails with "owner should sign tokenId". How can i create v,s,r using python web3.

Comment: Is the private key from the contract's owner? Can you show an example of the message to be signed? What's `tokenId` type? uint256, bytes32, ...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your private key is "mywalletprivatekey".
Private keys shall be hexadecimal (only hex chars) and 64 chars long !

Using `private_key = "4d9e599423f0a37115c35f1dc4b749a4754545e4172d3901260a484512eee4d6"` (this dont hold any ether) shall work !